# cassandra goes down when spark 1.6 try to read from it

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am using spark 1.6 with cassandra version Cassandra 2.1.8. I have a setup of 2 dataceters with 3 cassandra machines and 2 spark worker machines. I was running spark 1.4 and my job was running fine. It was fetching from cassandra, processing it.

When I run my job with spark 1.6, and when the job tries to read from cassandra, my servers in cassandra goes down and spark driver hangs in 24th task with worker machine logs reading as Partition rdd_5_266 not found, computing it

What can be the issue? Is it the issue with spark?

Additionally I can see this message as well in the worker logs
Could not acquire notifications lock within 60 seconds, ignoring UP notification for loc1dc2node1/10.0.2.172:9042

Also I tried enabling debug logs and saw this message
16/03/08 11:53:39 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0, runningTasks: 4

this line is printed again and again

There are millions of records in cassandra

Adding the logs for one of the executor in spark
http://www.filedropper.com/stderr

Let me add few more things here
1 i am filtering records based on addedtime which is part of cluster key
2 spark job is able to run fine with spark 1.4 and cassandra conector 1.4
3 i am using the latest spark 1.6 and cassandra 1.5 connector

Is there any change that went in from 1.4 to 1.5 in cassandra connector in a way of reading records which is making nodes crash

Comment: I don't have any experience with Spark over C*, but I did hear from someone who recommended not to work with any version (Cassandra) under 2.2 - maybe that could help. Also are you using the Datastax connector?

Comment: Yes i am using datastax connector. Can you please point me out any link which states not to use cassandra with a lower version

Comment: From the latest Spark Summit, https://spark-summit.org/east-2016/events/lambda-at-weather-scale/ slide #70 , just something that stuck with me... but I was wrong, it was >= 2.18 so you're ok... But lot's of potential useful lessons and recs otherwise in that talk

Comment: So when I try to count in my spark job, my one of the nodes in cassandra goes down with OOM. I am suspecting a cassandra connector issue. I did not face this issue in connector 1.4 with the same spark job

Comment: connector or possibly a hot-spot (bad key distribution)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105650/discussion-between-nipun-and-moshe-eshel).

Comment: Here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880657/sparksql-pushdown-filtering-not-working-in-spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: Happy you found a solution, 99/100 the answer is in the code.